# Benchmark Approach to compare two expression evaluators?

Tags: c#, performance, expression, performance-testing, query-performance

My current requirement to compare two expression evaluators with one expression over a data of 1000 rows to record the processing time.

My expression is:

```
if ( val1 > 0 ) 
then (
       ( val2 / val3 ) >= 34 and ( val4 / val5 ) <= 4500
     ) 
else ( 
      if ( val1 equals 0) 
      then true 
      else false
    )
```

I'm going to use 1000 different values of val1, val2, val3, val4 and val5 variables and try to iterate it over a loop. I need to record the processing results that how many seconds does it take to evaluate 1000 records over a single expression.

The expression evaluators I'm going to use are: NCalc [ https://ncalc.codeplex.com/] and Expression Evaluator [https://csharpeval.codeplex.com/].
Please suggest me an approach to record the benchmark results in C#. Can it be done using a simple console application in C# or Is there any 3rd party tools available that I can use?

Comment: Well the final application to which I'm going to implement the expression evaluator is C#. So yes, pretty sure it's C#.

Comment: Well, you can use `Stopwatch` class and get the time elapsed in a console application.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use a simple timer using `Stopwatch`:

```
var timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start();

// Do your stuff

timer.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("This operation took " + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms.");
```

Comment: There is no point in using `var` here since you statically know the type you are instantiating. Though it's all OK but it makes the code less readable.

Comment: I would consider that a matter of personal opinion (var is shorter, while repeating "`Stopwatch`" twice would be redundant, as it is obvious).In any case it is completely irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Checking it now :)